# How to detect a button click - logic error code provided

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What I want to do is, when I click the button once it should get highlighted (I am loading an image to show the highlighted effect), and when I click the button again (for the second time) it should remove the highlighted image and add a normal image. It should also add and remove elements from a Mutable Array.

But what is happening is that, when I click (once or several times) it only adds images, and does not remove any. Help me please

**Code**
I am adding a button. The below 2 lines are placed in the `viewdidload` method

```
UIButton *but= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    // then i set the size etc, and do the following

        [but addTarget:self action:@selector(butclick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    -(void)butclick:(id)sender{

        if([sender isSelected]==NO) {
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [sender setSelected:YES];

            [self.mutArry addObject:[sender titleForState:UIControlStateSelected]];

        } else {
            [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nothighlighter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [sender setSelected:NO];
            [self.mutArry removeObject:[sender titleForState:UIControlStateSelected]];

        }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it only adds images, and does not remove any"?

Comment: It remains in the highlighted state (As in the highlighted.png) and does not execute the else block when i click the button for the 2nd time

Answer (score 0):

u might want to use a BOOL (like a flag) to use it instead of using the highlight idea.

toggle it with each press, and according to its value perform ur operation, it will always add a value once and remove a value the next press. the first is according to what the initial value of that flag is.

```
    if (flag)
    {
    //add your object and set to highlight
       flag = NO;
    }else
    {
       flag = yes;
       //remove object and set to not highlighted
    }
```

set the flag to NO when when it was found true, and to YES when it was found false. ensures it will keep changing

Comment: I updated my post with an idea of the code. I mean by set to highlight is to change your image.

Comment: what Ehab suggesting is that you create a BOOL (boolean) variable at header, so that you can determine when the button is already load the images or no. so the basic logic is, on your button method, you add the BOOL, with IF statement. if the BOOL is YES, do : attach images, and then set the BOOL to "NO", so that the next time the button is pressed, it will detect that the BOOL is NO, hence do the different action (in which your case, it would be removing the image and set the BOOL back to YES)

Answer (score 0):

Have the following property defined and synthesized in that class

```
BOOL selected;
```

in viewDidLoad, set is to false

```
self.selected = NO;
```

Now do the following:

```
-(void)butclick:(id)sender{

    if(!self.selected) {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlighted.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.selected =  YES;

        [self.mutArry addObject:[sender titleForState:UIControlStateSelected]];

    } else {
        [sender setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nothighlighter.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.selected = NO;
        [self.mutArry removeObject:[sender titleForState:UIControlStateSelected]];

    }
```

}